# How could I debug a node.js App deploy on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Hi is there a way to debug an node.js app deployed on heroku server.

I cannot debug it locally since the app is receiving some post request from a 3rd party, and I don't have a public IP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 40):

I don't know why Heroku doesn't highlight this better, but the documentation you need for remote debugging with Heroku is on this [Heroku Exec (SSH tunneling) page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec). Currently it's node.js information needs a bit of an update to support the newer inspector protocol, but the important details are all there.

First you need to edit the `Procfile` at the root of your project tree to tell Heroku to start Node with debugging enabled:

```
web: node --inspect ./server.js (or ./app.js or whatever your entry point is)
```

Then you need to use the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) utility to tunnel the debugging port between your computer and your Heroku application. If you don't have that installed already, read the docs on how to install it and log it into your Heroku account.

To enable the connection you'll need to run this once:

```
heroku ps:exec
```

or if you run multiple Heroku apps:

```
heroku ps:exec -a my-app-name
```

Once you get a `$` command prompt, hit ctrl-C to exit.

Next, start the tunnel:

```
heroku ps:forward 9229 [-a my-app-name]
```

Now your application is available from any IDE that supports Node.js debugging. For [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_remote-debugging), you'll want to create a `launch.json` configuration entry that looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Heroku",
    "address": "localhost",
    "port": 9229,
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "remoteRoot": "/app"
},
```

You should now be able to start the debugging session in your editor and have it connect to your running app within a few seconds. All the normal debugging features, including breakpoints, call stacks, variable inspection etc should work.

Comment: This was just perfect!
Although one thing I don't understand is, why I have to run `ps:exec` and `ps:forward` side by side and specify the protocol in my `launch.json`.
I use ssh-tunneling to attach to my servers on aws and I can easily connect by just ssh but it doesn't work with heroku and doesn't allow me to attach if I am only running `ps:forward` command
Anyway, this worked for me :D

Comment: can you make a video of it

Comment: I just did this and didn't work, do I still have something more to configure ? it prompts a message that says "Can not connect to the target: socket hang up"

Comment: Official Document : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec

Comment: Right on the money.  Lifesaver.

Answer (score 6):

2019 Answer for Webstorm 2019.2
Not much changed but still:

1. Create a file name `Procfile` (no extension) --> Edit it:

   ```
    web: node --inspect=9090 ./server.js
   ```

   (or ./app.js or whatever your entry point is)
2. **Deploy the code with the new Procfile!**
3. Enable a connection - Open Terminal and run:

   ```
    heroku ps:exec -a [YOUR_APP_NAME]
   ```

Once you get a $ command prompt write:

```
    exit
```

in Terminal:

```
    heroku ps:forward 9090 -a [YOUR_APP_NAME]
```

3. Create a "Run Configuration":

- "Edit Configurations" --> Click on the + --> "Attach to node/Chrome" --> change port to 9090 & name it.
  [image]
- Select "Chrome or Node > 6.3 started with --inspect"
- Ok
- Click the debug

Now you are suppose to be attached to your heroku server.

In the end: Remove the Procfile and deploy again without it.

Comment: Thank you for adding a specific step for Webstorm !

Answer (score 3):

Fast and easy is just to login to heroku, go to your app and click on the More button. [image]

Or in console in your project folder type `heroku logs tail`

Comment: You are right! That's a good start, but I need a debugger. I must check a Json request that I receive. In theory its contents could be accessed using req.body, but  req.body throws an undefined error for the body attribute. If I log the req, I get [object] if I log Json.stringify(req) I receive some circular error. I have no choice but to inspect the req object :(

Comment: @RaresI have you succeed to overcome it? could not log the req either - same issue. I'll be grateful for any help

Comment: @chenop sorry mate, I can't remember what I've done. It was a long time ago